# Nesting Scenarios? How could I have a Scenario use other Scenerios in its Given statement?

Tags: bdd, python-behave

I am exploring using *behave* in testing a chatbot.

I can define simple scenarios like

```
Scenario: Asked a widget function question
   Given a new dialog
   When the visitor asks
   """
   What do your widgets do?
   """
   Then bot should explain widget function
```

```
Scenario: Asked a widget cost question
   Given a new dialog
   When the visitor asks
   """ 
   How much does your widget cost?
   """
   Then bot should provide widget cost
```

The trouble is that a good chat bot needs to preserve context.  If it successfully preserves context, then sequence matters.  If both of the above scenarios pass, it would not mean that a dialog where those questions were asked one after the other wouldn't throw an error.

For that you'd need a scenario like this

```
Scenario: Asked a widget function question and price question
   Given a new dialog
   When the visitor asks
   """
   What do your widgets do?
   """
   And the bot explains widget function

   When the visitor asks
   """ 
   How much does your widget cost?
   """
   Then bot should provide widget cost
```

Of course, writing a scenario that has a dialog preamble in the `Given` block for each dialog one wants to test would be extremely repetitive.

I would rather "nest" scenarios somehow.  Something like this (I know it's not valid).

```
 Scenario: Asked a widget cost question
   Given user Asked a widget function question
   When the visitor asks
   """ 
   How much does your widget cost?
   """
   Then bot should provide widget cost
```

How could I do something something like this in *behave*?  I was thinking of perhaps using the `given`, `when`, and `then` decorators *inside* `step_impl` functions...

Answer (score 0):

Make each of the previous messages a `Given`.

```
Scenario: Asked a widget function question and price question
    Given a new dialog
    And the visitor already asked
        """
        What do your widgets do?
        """
    When the visitor asks
        """
        How much does your widget cost?
        """
    Then bot should provide widget cost
```

The `Given` statement for previous questions can explicitly wait for the correct answer, or it could just wait for any answer before proceeding to the next step. This way the prerequisites for getting a widget price are clearly indicated as Given's, fitting nicely into the Given-When-Then style of a BDD test. You also aren't cluttering up your scenario with a bunch of Then's that are not directly related to the scenario.